# Lotus Notes embeds SSRS csv data in body not as attachment

Tags: lotus-notes, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a MS Reporting Services subscription implemented which emails out a CSV report as an attachment. The email is received with the attached CSV file no problem, EXCEPT for users with Lotus Notes. 
With LN users the contents of the csv file are embedded in the body of the email.

Any suggestions on this?

UPDATE: Might Lotus be handing this differently due to the content-type? Seems as though SSRS uses text/plain. Will SSRS allow me to change the content type?

Comment: I believe this question might find an answer at ServerFault.  I'd bet there's an admin setting that can help control or workaround your issue.  My only other suggestion is to send the reports as RTFs from SSRS, or see if you can package the report as a ZIP file before sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the ContentDisposition solved this.

[c# generated csv file sent via email embedded to bottom of email in lotus note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891598/c-generated-csv-file-sent-via-email-embedded-to-bottom-of-email-in-lotus-note)

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a setting in Lotus Notes whether to embed attachments. Definitely not something SSRS can control. In ReportingServices.config you can try setting the MIMEType for the CSV rendering extension, but it's unlikely that it will have an effect...or that it will fix the problem even if it does.

```
        <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.CsvRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.CsvRendering">
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <MIMEType>application/csv</MIMEType>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```

*Note: MIMEType is listed as a configurable setting for the XML rendering extension, but not for CSV. Setting it may have no effect at all or may cause your reporting services service to fail to load.*

CSV Rendering Extension settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365.aspx

XML Rendering Extension settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154691.aspx

Comment: I do believe that it is somehow related to how SSRS is delivering the reports. We recently moved to SSRS from Crystal Reports and with CR we were not experiencing this problem.